# Limit multiple textbox to number

Tags: c#, winforms

I found the following solution to limit textbox to numbers.  I have 20 textBoxes in my GUI is there a cleaner way than making 20 of these functions?

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
        e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
 }
```

Comment: Create a function once and hook all 20 textboxes' keypress events to that same handler.

Comment: @Tarik Can you handle User paste?

Comment: @Jimi Have I answered the OP question?

Comment: I dont care for paste I can disable it.

Comment: Why not use the `NumericUpDown` control?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to replace the standard TextBox Controls that need this feature, with a Custom Control that can also filter the User input when text is pasted in the Control or when the Control's `Text` Property is set in the Designer, using the PropertyGrid.

If you only handle the `KeyPress` event, you cannot prevent a bad paste.
I think it's also better to filter what is set in the `Text` Property, to avoid a *misunderstanding*.

Test this simple Custom TextBox Control: it handles direct User input and text pasted at run-time.
Setting the `UserPaste` Property to `Disallow`, pastes are ignored, while setting it to `NumbersOnly` (default) allows just numbers: if mixed chars are pasted in the Control, only the numbers are preserved.

To also allow the input of comma and dot, change the Regex in `[^0-9,.\b]`.

The Text property set in the Designer is also filtered.

To replace the existing TextBox Controls with the this Custom Control, you can use the Find/Replace function (usually activated with <kbd>CTRL+H</kbd>) in Visual Studio:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[ToolboxItem(true)]
[DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class TextBoxNumbers : TextBox
{
    private Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^0-9\b]", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public TextBoxNumbers() { }

    public override string Text {
        get => base.Text;
        set { if (!base.Text.Equals(value)) base.Text = regex.Replace(value, ""); }
    }

    public enum PasteAction {
        NumbersOnly,
        Disallow
    }

    [DefaultValue(PasteAction.NumbersOnly)]
    public PasteAction UserPaste { get; set; }

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString())) {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg) {
            case NativeMethods.WM_PASTE:
                switch (UserPaste) {
                    case PasteAction.Disallow:
                        return;
                    case PasteAction.NumbersOnly:
                        string text = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);
                        text = regex.Replace(text, "");
                        NativeMethods.SendMessage(this.Handle, NativeMethods.EM_REPLACESEL, 1, text);
                        return;
                }
                break;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

**`NativeMethods` class:**

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

private class NativeMethods
{
    internal const int WM_PASTE = 0x0302;
    internal const int EM_REPLACESEL = 0xC2;

    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);
}
```

Comment: The WndProc() doesn't look right, the Text property is special and always cached instead of reading it back from the native control. As-is, the code would cause a mismatch between Text and the control content, that's bad.  Keep it simple by assigning SelectedText instead.

Comment: @Hans Passant  Thanks for the comment. The original Custom Control (the one I have *extracted* this piece of code from) is using `EM_REPLACESEL` directly to bypass the two calls to `SendMessage` that set `EM_LIMITTEXT` to `0` and then again to `MaxLength` right after `EM_REPLACESEL` is called (the base class does the same exact thing when you set the `SelectedText` Property). This is done because this value (MaxLength) is handled in a different way (not relevant here). I have tested this short version: the `Text` value is preserved and also calling `Undo()` restores the previous Text.

Comment: @HansPassant If you have an indication that this can go wrong in specific conditions, or if you have the chance to test this control, I'm glad to hear it and change the implementation.

Comment: Im new to C# and your code looks complicated but I'm interested in custom control.  Would this be a good approach if during run time I want to change the format of the textbox based on user selection in another field eg. limit to 3 decimal or 0 decimal based on another selected option?

Comment: I find this kind of solution more interesting, it's something you can build on, over time, add more features, make it behave the way you want. It may appear complicated, at first (a little more if you're new to C# and WinForms :), because you need to learn how these Controls work, under the hood. Implementations like this are common in WinForms (old base Controls, lack of flexibility...) -- You can format the input as you like: `CultureInfo.NumberFormat` (see [NumberFormatInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo)) gives you the information needed.

Comment: Then you can use [Decimal.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse) to validate the Text and `ToString()` to format it, specifying `N` (Culture-specific number formats) or `F` (numbers with just the Culture-specific decimal separator) + the number of decimal places, set using a Property of your Custom Control (e.g., `N2`, `F2`--> `[decimal vaule].ToString("N" + [Decimal Places specified)`. -- If you don't care about all this and you don't dislike the Buttons of a NumericUpDown, use that instead. You'll get here anyway, sooner or later :)

Answer (score 0):

My simple and go-to solution would be to wirte the methode once, after that go to the desginer and select every of your texboxes that need it, click on the event-button in the propperties, scroll to the KeyPress Event and click on it once, now a dropdown-arrow should apear, select your methode there - done.

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
 {
     e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);
 }
```